For stabilizer codes, why does the error syndrome not depend on the codeword?
While reading through some lecture notes on quantum error correction, I read the statement:
"In particular, the syndrome doesn’t depend on the specific codeword, only on the Pauli
error."
I'm trying to come up with a proof as to why this is the case. I know that codewords are vectors in the shared +1 eigenvalue subspace among the Pauli errors in the stabilizer group, $S$.
I suppose the question is whether given a Pauli error (not in the stabilizer group), $P$, does $P$ have the same error syndrome for all codewords? This seems like it would not be true because we only know how Pauli errors in $S$ act on the codespace.

You can understand the syndrome by error propagation from the source of the error to the measurements. For example you can consider how an X error at a specific location affects the syndrome measurement. If it propagates to an X error right before a Z-measurement, for example, it flips the outcome. You see that this is completely independent of the state.

I'm still a bit confused on your answer. Is there maybe a simple explicit example of what you are saying?

I think I understand now. A measurement of a stabilizer after an error occurs will be determined by whether or not that stabilizer commutes or anti-commutes with the error (Pauli operators must always commute/anticommute). Therefore applying an error E to the entire +1 subspace just translates it a subspace defined by the error syndrome.

If the syndrome would depend on the codeword, this would imply that the syndrome measurement reveals information about the encoded qubit, which would necessarily destroy the encoded information (otherwise, no-cloning would be violated).
